# How to change the hibernate logging level in JHipster?

Tags: hibernate, logging, jhipster

I have a use case in which I run multiple thousand SQL queries and the logging set as it is, writing every query out to the console takes a lot of time and makes the call time out on the client side. I tried setting the logback.loglevel property of the dev profile in the pom.xml to ERROR but that didn't help.

So my questions are:

- Is it possible to configure the log level for an individual REST call?
- How can I globally configure the log levels for the application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is changing spring.jpa.show_sql: true in https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app/blob/v6.10.5/src/main/resources/config/application-dev.yml#L51 to 'false'  what you're looking for?

Answer (score 8):

Besides changing the property `spring.jpa.show_sql` in `application*.yml` files, you can also try changing Logback's configurations:

In the files `src/main/resources/logback-spring.xml` and `src/test/resources/logback-test.xml` you can add the following configurations:

To get detailed log SQL information including SQL parameter values:

```
<logger name="org.hibernate.SQL" level="DEBUG"/>
<logger name="org.hibernate.type" level="TRACE"/>
```

To make SQL less chatty:

```
<logger name="org.hibernate.SQL" level="DEBUG"/>
<logger name="org.hibernate.type" level="TRACE"/>
```

As an added bonus, explicitly declaring these loggers in logback configuration files will make Hibernate's logging use Logback's layout configuration, e.g. showing the time and the name of the executing thread.

`spring.jpa.show_sql` set to `true` takes precedence over the Logback configuration - including its less helpful layout without time and without the name of the execuding thread. So for my own purposes, **I prefer to set `spring.jpa.show_sql` to `false`** and instead configure `logback-spring.xml` (where logging configuration aspects should be placed anyways). There, you can then set [Spring profile-specific logging levels](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35725540/923560):

```
<springProfile name="dev, staging">
    <logger name="org.hibernate.SQL" level="DEBUG"/> <!-- set org.hibernate.SQL to DEBUG to see SQL statements -->
    <logger name="org.hibernate.type" level="INFO"/> <!-- set org.hibernate.type to TRACE to see SQL parameters -->
</springProfile>
<springProfile name="prod">
    <logger name="org.hibernate.SQL" level="INFO"/> <!-- set org.hibernate.SQL to DEBUG to see SQL statements -->
    <logger name="org.hibernate.type" level="INFO"/> <!-- set org.hibernate.type to TRACE to see SQL parameters -->
</springProfile>
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to change two files as below:

**application.yml**:

```
spring:

...

jpa:

   ...
   show_sql: true
   ...
```

**logback-spring.xml**

```
<logger name="org.hibernate.SQL" level="DEBUG">;
```

Good luck.