# Configure logback using several profiles

Tags: spring-boot, logback

I´m trying to split my logback.xml by profiles under springboot, this my approach:

**logback-prod.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml" />
<property name="LOG_FILE" value="${LOG_FILE:-${LOG_PATH:-${LOG_TEMP:- ${java.io.tmpdir:-/tmp}}/}spring.log}"/>
<include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/file- appender.xml" />

<root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
</root>
</configuration>
```

**logback-dev.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml" />
<include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/console-appender.xml" />

<root level="DEBUG">
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
</root>
```

**logback.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<include resource="logback-${spring.profiles.active}.xml"/>

<root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
</root>
```

And finally use:

```
-Dspring.profiles.active=dev
 or
-Dspring.profiles.active=prod
```

I got in console:

```
13:01:44,673 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@2:16 - no  applicable action for [configuration], current ElementPath  is [[configuration][configuration]]
13:01:44,674 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@3:81 - no applicable action for [include], current ElementPath  is [[configuration][configuration][include]]
13:01:44,674 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@4:89 - no applicable action for [include], current ElementPath  is [[configuration][configuration][include]]
13:01:44,674 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@6:25 - no applicable action for [root], current ElementPath  is [[configuration][configuration][root]]
13:01:44,674 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@7:39 - no applicable action for [appender-ref], current ElementPath  is [[configuration][configuration][root][appender-ref]]
13:01:44,675 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.RootLoggerAction - Setting level of ROOT logger to INFO
```

Answer (score 224):

[Spring boot documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.1.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html#boot-features-custom-log-configuration) recommends to use `logback-spring.xml` rather than `logback.xml` and in it you can use spring profile tag:

```
<configuration>
  <springProfile name="workspace">
    ...
  </springProfile>
  <springProfile name="dev,prd">
    ...
  </springProfile>
</configuration>
```

Comment: According to: 
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.1.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html#boot-features-custom-log-configuration

You have to separate the profiles by "|" sign not "," comma. As bellow:

<springProfile name="dev | staging">
 <!-- configuration to be enabled when the "dev" or "staging" profiles are active -->
</springProfile>

Answer (score 49):

If you want different logback configuration files for different profiles, you can change it from your `application-*.properties` files.

For example in your `application-prod.properties` you can say:

```
logging.config=src/main/resources/logback-prod.xml
```

Comment: or yml -> logging.config: src/main/resources/logback-prod.xml

Comment: This works when run in an IDE, but not when packaged and executed on another machine. You can use logging.config=classpath:logback-prod.xml to search on the classpath (https://stackoverflow.com/a/31631289/3340372)

Answer (score 7):

Alternative way in `logback.xml` config file, with separation of config depends on Spring Profile can look like:

```
<!--    Loggers setup according to Spring Profile-->
<springProfile name="localdev">
    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
        <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
    </root>
    <logger name="com.myapp" level="debug" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
        <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
    </logger>
</springProfile>

<springProfile name="test">
    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
    </root>
    <logger name="com.myapp" level="debug">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
    </logger>
</springProfile>
```

Answer (score 2):

Included XMLs should have top node `included` instead of `configuration`.

Answer (score 0):

According to:  [Profile-specific Configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.1.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html#_profile_specific_configuration)

You have to separate the profiles by "`|`" sign not "`,`" comma. As bellow:

```
<springProfile name="dev | staging">
    <!-- configuration to be enabled when the "dev" or "staging" profiles are active -->
</springProfile>
```