# How to set the location of logback.xml when deploying into tomcat?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat, logback

In my spring boot application, in `application.properties` I specified:

```
logging.config=classpath:logback-LOCAL.xml
```

This file is located under `src/main/resources`, which I configured to be a source folder in my maven pom.xml:

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    ...
</build>
```

This works fine when running the application as standalone. But when building a `.war`-File and deploying it to tomcat, then the logback configuration is ignored.

Using `logback.xml` as filename (or `logback-spring.xml`) would work fine, but I want to use `logback-LOCAL.xml` (for to separate logging configs of different environments).

How can I specifiy the location of my `logback.xml` file in my `application.properties`, so that it will take effect in my tomcat deployed web application?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35725540/2834978) could work for you I think.

Comment: @LuisMuñoz `<springProfile>` would work, but I want to use completely separate files. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Why you are using other filename than logback defines? With one of these *logback-spring.xml*, *logback.xml*, *logback-spring.groovy*, *logback.groovy* filenames spring will load it from classpath. If you use another filename than you can use the propertiy `logging.file`in combination with `logging.config`. Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: Setting `logging.config=classpath:logback-LOCAL.xml` *and* `logging.file=logback-LOCAL.xml` still does not work. I want to use different files per environment and switch them by profiles. I am aware of the `<springProfile>` tags, but I would prefer separate files.