# spring boot How to turn off the use of log back

Tags: java, spring-boot

It is often not necessary to use logback printing during dev development. How to turn off logback printing logs while in dev environment.
Turn on log back log printing in production environment.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2sqS1.png)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that answer your question but you can check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35651241/configure-logback-using-several-profiles), maybe you need to configure your dev profile if you have more profiles, if not to create them.

Answer (score 0):

To disable logging you can set the root logger to `off`. Add the following to your `application.properties`:

```
logging.level.root=off
```

See [this section of the reference docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.logging.log-levels).

If you want completely silent output you can also set:

```
spring.main.banner-mode=off
```

This is covered in [this section of the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.spring-application.banner).

If you want this setting only in certain you can use [profile specific property files](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config.files.profile-specific).

Comment: For the requested case, wouldn't the best way be to put this in `src/test/resources`?